# Почему ПОМОЩНИК пишется через Щ

Tags: орфография

Когда меня спросили как пишется слово *помощник* я со 100 % уверенностью сказал, что через *ш*. Как выяснилось я был неправ, но интересно другое.

1. Почему так пишется, уж не потому что проверочное слово *помощь* (мне это объяснение кажется некорректным)?
2. Какие есть в языке похожие примеры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ДеNiZz, "помощь" и "помощник" - однокоренные, поэтому и пишутся в общей части (это здесь корень) одинаково. Это вкратце.

~1. В русском языке превалирующим является морфологический принцип. В частности, корни обычно пишутся во всех словах одинаково, про исключения - отдельный разговор, обычно они возникают тогда, когда орфоэпическое (правильное) произношение вступает в противоречие с морфологическим написанием.

~2. Niemand, хоть и ответил невпопад, одну вещь сказал разумную. Что считать ***похожим*** примером? Конечно, проверять "помощник" через "конечно" и прочие "примеров навалом" нельзя. Там разного происхождения шипящие звуки и буквы, им соответствующие. Да и произношение не такое уж однозначное, современные нормы близки к тому, чтобы узаконить произношение ЧН именно как ЧН, но это именно Ч, не Щ.

Если "похожие" это те, в которых на первое место выступает морфологический принцип, то их действительно предостаточно.

Поручик - от "поручать", корень "рук" - с чередованием "Ч<К".
Извозчик - от "извоз" + "чик".

В каком-то смысле даже "солнце" с его нечитаемым "Л" - из этой серии, произношение не совсем соответствует написанию.

Есть и обратные примеры: "свадьба" - от сват, свататься.

Возникает вопрос, почему в "помощник" и подобных сохраняется принцип морфологического написания? В частности потому, что орфоэпические правила предписывают или позволяют читать "ЩН" именно как "ШН", это общее положение, в разной степени реализуемое во многих подобных сочетаниях. Менять орфографию не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Помощь - помощ/ник - Щ произносится как Ш, **фонетическое чередование на письме не отражается (согласно основному правилу русского письма),**  морфемы сохраняют свой исходный состав.

Чередование Щ/Ш нестандартное и, скорее всего, связано с удобством произношения - мягкий Щ перед мягким Н и "мягкой" гласной И произносится с трудом.

Сравнить: мощь - мощный, перед  "твердым" Ы мягкий Щ произносится нормально.

Comment: _Sibylla:  Чередование Щ/Ш нестандартное и, скорее всего, связано с удобством произношения - мягкий Щ перед мягким Н и "мягкой" гласной И произносится с трудом_. ===  Гм… А в этих словах тоже с трудом: _**сокровищница, сообщник, хищник?..**_

Comment: Slava, так надо всё окружение учитывать: сокровищница, сообщник - здесь Ш никак не произнесешь, а вот в слове хищник это можно сделать, да только словарь строго запрещает.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы обманулись, потому что произносится-то в "помощнике" звук [ш]. А пищется Щ, потому что действительно от "помощь".
2. Примеры типа "конечно" (произносится [ш]) считаете вы похожими? В таком случае этих примеров навалом.

Comment: 1. Разве можно проверять написание согласных таким образом?

Comment: *Разве можно проверять написание согласных таким образом?* - ***проверять*** нельзя. Это по-другому называется.